# How do I get the stationary distribution of a Markov chain matrix from SVD?

Tags: markov-process, eigenvalues, svd, numpy

I have a matrix that represents a Markov chain.

```
M = np.array([
    [0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
    [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5],
    [0, 0.333, 0.333, 0, 0.333],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
])
```

To compute the stationary distribution, I use the Power Method, within a few iterations, I get convergence.

```
np.diag(M.dot(M).dot(M).dot(M).dot(M).dot(M).dot(M).dot(M).dot(M).dot(M))
```

And the output is

```
array([0.08759149, 0.43795601, 0.1459856 , 0.10948932, 0.2189781 ])
```

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791728/python-code-explanation-for-stationary-distribution-of-a-markov-chain?utm_source=pocket_mylist), I can also use `np.linalg.eig()` to compute the stationary distribution from `U` based on the index of the eigenvalue in `S` closest to 1. The output is the same as with the Power Method.

```
S, U = np.linalg.eig(M.T)
(U[:,np.isclose(S, 1)][:,0] / U[:,np.isclose(S, 1)][:,0].sum()).real
```

I have been reading that SVD can also be used to find the stationary distribution.

```
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(M.T)
```

However, no matter how I try, I cannot get the same result as with the Power method or `np.linalg.eig()`.

```
U[:,0] / U[:,0].sum() # array([0.0233, 0.5642, 0.1184, 0.0589, 0.2350])
U[0,:] / U[0,:].sum() # array([0.5836, 0.4079, -0.4530, -0.4341, 0.8956])
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?